# How to show bytes value iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I am trying to output the `bytes` value of iptables. I tried the following:

```
sudo iptables -nvL INPUT --line-numbers
```

I got the following output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      316 18844 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW limit: avg 60/sec burst 20
2        0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
```

I also tried:

```
sudo iptables -nvL INPUT --line-numbers | grep ACCEPT
```

But I'm not getting ONLY the `bytes` value.

I have no ideo how I can extract the `bytes` value (18844 and 0) from this command.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the `bytes` value is the 3rd column, so you can write:

```
iptables -nvL INPUT | awk '/policy/ {next} /ACCEPT/ {print $3}'
```

Given your example output above, that produces:

```
18844
```

The first pattern in that awk script (`/policy/ {next}`) is to skip the first line, which otherwise would match on `ACCEPT`.

Comment: Your answer wasn't 100% correct for me, but I works when I changen the "$3" to "$2". I marked it as correct, because without your answer I would have no idea how I could sove it. Thanks you so much.